# background image toggle only on single image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The above is a fiddle in which i want to toggle or show/hide the background image(i.e. tick mark) onclick and also select the following offer in database (mysql). I am able to show the tick mark but not hide it. Please help.

```
$(function() {
 $('.listing-content').click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1Do.png)');
 });
})
```

When a listing-content element is clicked, I need the other listing-content elements to have the background image removed also? So no more than one is ticked at a time?

Answer (score 0):

On .listing-content click, execute this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.listing-content', function() {
  $('.listing-content').css('background-image', '');
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1Do.png)');
});
```

or

```
$('.listing-content').removeAttr('style'); //removes all inline css
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a control to check if CSS image is set. Look here for demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kpsbbjk4/

```
$(function() {
 $('.listing-content').click(function() {

 //this code to control and untick current clicked item if it is ticked
 if ($(this).css('background-image')=='url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1Do.png")'){
  $(this).css('background-image', '');

 }else{
  //this code to remove all css images so that new item get ticked
 $('.listing-content').css('background-image', '');

  $(this).css('background-image', 'url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg1Do.png")'); 
  }

 });
})
```

Comment: Here is how you do it via class: https://jsfiddle.net/kpsbbjk4/1/ (which is better approach actually)